# Print an entire panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have this interface

[image]

I want to print all the data in the first tab (the first tab has a docked panel that has all the `labels` and `texboxes` in it) including the picture.

I have used

```
    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {   
            string data = "Title : \t" + cmbTitle.Text + "\n\nFirst Name : \t" + txtFirstName.Text + "\n\nLast Name : \t" + txtLastName.Text + "\n\nMiddle Name : \t" + txtMiddleName.Text + "\n\nFull Name : \t" + txtFullName.Text + "\n\nNick Name : \t" +
                txtNick.Text + "\n\nGender : \t" + cmbGender.Text + "\n\nCountry : \t" + cmbHomeCountry.Text + "\n\nState : \t" + txtState.Text + "\n\nEmail Address : " + txtEmail.Text;
            Image img = resizeImage(pictureBox1.Image, new Size(300, 300));
            e.Graphics.DrawString("Personal Data for " + txtFullName.Text, new Font("Lucida Calligraphy", 20, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 5, 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 5, 70);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(data, new Font("MS Reference Sans Serif", 20, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 5, 420);
        }
   }
```

This worked but i want to know if there is any better way to print the entire panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do a 'print screen' of the control you can use [Control.DrawToBitmap()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx)